# Haw enable thumbnails in preview? ngx-gallery-9

Tags: angular9

Haw enable thumbnails in preview? ngx-gallery-9
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-gallery-9

http://prntscr.com/s980ef

Answer (score 0):

actually ngx gallery doesn't have thumbnail in preview on fullscreen mode
you can use thumbnails on default mode